403 forbidden error in Django admin even though superuser was already created
Recently, i cloned a project from github to get more familiar with projects written in Django. Previously, everything was running fine, but today when i tried to sign into the Django admin page it gave me this error:
403 Forbidden
And returned this in my terminal:
Forbidden (Permission denied): /admin/auth/group/add/
raise PermissionDenied
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied

Which confused me, since there was already a superuser created. Can anyone help me solve this?
Edit: Someone asked me to share the repo that i used so here it is:
Online Examination repository
Traceback added below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner       
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response   
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 688, in wrapper      
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view     
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1886, in add_view    
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view     
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1747, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\afric\.virtualenvs\Online-Examination-System-aZtpAN9a\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1763, in _changeform_view
    raise PermissionDenied
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied


You need to post code, or share repo so we can replicate the problem, we cannot help without any code. What I can say you already know, the user does not have permission to create the object.

Sorry about that! The repo has been posted now

I cloned and tried your code on my machine, and it seems to work just fine..  Can you share the full traceback when you get this error.

You stated "since there was already a superuser created".  Did you create this superuser using python manage.py createsuperuser?

Yes i did! Later on i created another superuser with the same command just incase there was a problem with the first account but the error still persisted.

I finaly realized my issue: I was logged in with a user's credentials that were not those of the admin! After gaining a proper link to the admin site, i simply logged out of that account and logged back in with my previous superuser credentials, and everything is works fine now! Thanks for the help!

I finaly realized my issue: I was logged in with a user's credentials that were not those of the admin! After gaining a proper link to the admin site, i simply logged out of that account and logged back in with my previous superuser credentials, and everything is works fine now! Thanks for the help, please close this question!

Glad it's solved. As a matter of fact, you could just delete your own question if you're so inclined. You will also be able to accept your own answer after 48 h. I also voted to close the question as "caused by a typo". It's up to you.
